# Rbinding elements of a list, but between each element add filler data

Tags: r

I am trying to prepare input data for a systems based ecological model. I currently have a data frame named "Precip" which has 64 columns, each column "X1", "X2", "X3", etc. is a model of 30 years worth of daily precipitation data(see below). I need to rbind each model on top of eachother so I have one row with all data stacked. However, between each model I need to add filler precipitation data which is just 365 days of 0 precipitation(see below). Essentially I need to create one dataframe or list which is rbind(X1,FillerPrecip,X2, FillerPrecip,X3,FillerPrecip, etc.).

I have tried turning both Precip and FillerPrecip into lists and using rbindlist, however it wouldn't allow me to bind FillerPrecip between each element of Precip.

```
> str(Precip)
'data.frame':   11322 obs. of  64 variables:
 $ X1   : num  0.11 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X2   : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X3   : num  0.3437 0.1464 0 0 0.0422 ...
 $ X4   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X5   : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X6   : num  0 0 0.0304 0 0 ...

> head(FillerPrecip)
  V1
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  0
6  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
PrecipVector <- c(sapply(seq_along(Precip), function(i) {
  c(Precip[,i], FillerPrecip)
}))
```

This will insert `FillerPrecip` after every column of `Precip`. The result will be a numeric vector, and you can convert it to a dataframe or list as needed.

Comment: Thank you! This worked just as well as the other method! I like the ability to set a data frame of filler data since I will have to use this same procedure for temperature and other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reshaping data from wide to long. Then by `X` group, `rbind` each subset of model:

```
# RESHAPE LONG
rdf <- reshape(df, varying = list(names(df)), times = names(df),
               timevar = "X", v.names = "FillerPrecip",
               new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")

# BY GROUP: rbind 365 ROWS OF ZERO INTO FillerPrecip COLUMN           
df_list <- by(rdf, rdf$X, function(sub)    
    rbind(sub, data.frame(X=NA, FillerPrecip = rep(0, 365), id = NA))    
)

# CONCATENATE INDIVIDUAL DFs INTO MASTER DF
final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/SHJQZ63000)